# Couldn't create org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart in Mac

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-tool-suite

I couldn't create a new maven project in spring test suite. Getting the following error

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.4 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.4
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.4 from ${env.ARTIFACTORY_URL} was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.4 from/to central (${env.ARTIFACTORY_URL}): Cannot access ${env.ARTIFACTORY_URL} with type default using the available connector factories: AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory,        BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.4 from ${env.ARTIFACTORY_URL} was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.4 from/to central (${env.ARTIFACTORY_URL}): Cannot access ${env.ARTIFACTORY_URL} with type default using the available connector factories: AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory, BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.4 from ${env.ARTIFACTORY_URL} was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.4 from/to central (${env.ARTIFACTORY_URL}): Cannot access ${env.ARTIFACTORY_URL} with type default using the available connector factories: AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory, BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.4 from ${env.ARTIFACTORY_URL} was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.4 from/to central (${env.ARTIFACTORY_URL}): Cannot access ${env.ARTIFACTORY_URL} with type default using the available connector factories: AetherRepositoryConnectorFactory, BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
```

Comment: you need set your proxy.

Comment: set proxy in? @sgrillon

Comment: Maven setting.xml

Comment: Thank you it is working now

Answer (score 0):

```
<mirrors>
   <mirror>
     <id>UK</id>
     <name>UK Central</name>
     <url>http://uk.maven.org/maven2</url>
     <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Adding the above to setting.xml would resolve the above error